# How to set format as hour in babel.dates.format_date?

Tags: python, python-babel

odoo ERP regroup by day as default :

```
data[k] = babel.dates.format_date(v, format="dd MMM yyyy", locale=context.get('lang', 'en_US')).
```

what i want to do is to change the format date from **day** to **hour** format.

I try to change the previous code line:

`data[k] = babel.dates.format_date(v, format="HH dd MMM yyyy", locale=context.get('lang', 'en_US'))`

but this return an error:

```
 AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

TO clarify i want to create custom date/time pattern, in which the hour must appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need `datetime` object for hour  not just `date`. try

`babel.dates.format_datetime`

See: http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/api/dates/